# Is there a way to read a data structure(eg:mapping) of a smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, ens

Ethereum's smart contract's data should be stored at Merkle Patricia tree, which is available on every full node. 
So is there a way to read a data structure(eg:mapping) of a smart contract.

More specially, I want to access ens smart contract's records mapping.
https://github.com/ethereum/ens/blob/master/contracts/ENS.sol line 15, in order 
to get all the name registered.

Comment: It is not possible to iterate over a mapping because the key values are not stored. For an already deployed contract one option is to trace every transaction that calls such contract.